# Change into passive voice :

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

**"I take good care of my books."**

If we *passivise* this sentence, which of the following will be *correct* and what's the *wrong* with the others?

> *1. My books are taken good care of.*
>
> *2. Good care is taken of my books.*
>
> *3. Good care of my books is taken.*

Comment: All three of those sentences are syntactically passive, but none of them are idiomatic. The third sentence in particular is extremely awkward because of the repetition of *care*.

Comment: What's going on? You asked the same question today on the grammar website _EF_ under the name of SandipKumar, where you also ask questions under the name of Sandip Kumar.

Comment: @BillJ, can't I seek opinions of experts from two reputed websites? Learning shouldn't be restricted.

Comment: You can, but you may get different answers, and then you won't know which one is correct!

Comment: @Jason Bassford, could you please grammatically explain whether the passive constructions given by me are ok or not.

Answer (score 2):

To include all the meaning, it would have to be
"Good care is taken of my books by me."
since good care could be taken of your books by your maid.

All of the examples, including the one I just proposed, sound awkward and  are unlikely to be said. Not everything should be passivized.

This is a passive expression that sounds natural:
"My books are well cared for."

Comment: "My books are well cared for" sounds ok. Could you please grammatically explain what's the wrong with the examples given by me? @Jack O'Flaherty

Comment: As they are written now, the first two are grammatical, though awkward and unidiomatic. The third example has incorrect word order, because the preposition phrase complement of "is taken" should not precede it.

Comment: The PP (of my books) modifies the noun 'care'. The NP ('good care of my books') is e complement (object) of the verb 'take'. Therefore, I = subject, take = verb, 'good care of my book' (NP) = object. Hence, the passive voice, as shown in the third example. Maybe it sounds awkward. But is it ungrammatical?

Comment: I don't know for sure that it is ungrammatical, but it is unidiomatic and awkward. I think that supersedes the question of grammaticality.